# Мне нужна некоторая помощь с кодом на python по выводу файлов

Tags: python

```
name=input("Для начала скажите,как вас зовут:")
print("Привет"+","+str(name)+"!")
help=input("Что мне вам показать?:")
if help="Обезьяна":
     ...
if help="ЖираФ":
...
else:
    print("я этого не знаю")
```

p.s:вместо строчек с точками мне нужна команда для вывода изображений из папки.
Так же,хотелось бы узнать,можно ли изображения включить в программу,что бы,отправив файл с прогой другу он без проблем выводил изображения на своём компьютере.

Comment: вроде эта информация в любой книжке по питону есть или даже на ютубе в любом видео

Answer (score 0):

Установите себе библиотеку [Pillow](https://pypi.org/project/Pillow/): `pip install Pillow`

А дальше показывайте:

```
from PIL import Image                                                                                
img = Image.open('animal.png')
img.show()
```

По поводу включения изображений, проще сделать относительные пути и отправить программу вместе с картинками. Компиляция файлов в один .exe или даже с ресурсным файлом является нетривиальной задачей. А так поищите на досуге как компилировать python в *.exe, особенно если у друга не установлен компилятор.